# Error:Unable to invoke action : The server is currently unavailable

Tags: apache, serverless-framework, openwhisk, serverless-architecture

I am doing a on prem setup of openwhisk using local couchdb installation on ubuntu 16.04 for which I downloaded the code from the github. I have followed all the steps of the setup, after the build, I have to run various playbooks
when is run the below playbook with the below command 
**ansible-playbook -i environments/local openwhisk.yml** 
I get error 
 **"error": "The server is currently unavailable (because it is overloaded or down for maintenance).",
  "code": 4**

when I check I found it is coming while executing installRouteMgmt.sh from /openwhisk/ansible/roles/routemgmt/files 
the line in the script which is throwing error is

```
enter code here`echo Installing routemgmt package.
$WSK_CLI -i -v --apihost "$APIHOST" package update --auth "$AUTH"  --shared no "$NAMESPACE/routemgmt" \
-a description "This experimental package manages the gateway API configuration." \
-p gwUser "$GW_USER" \
-p gwPwd "$GW_PWD" \
-p gwUrl "$GW_HOST" \
-p gwUrlV2 "$GW_HOST_V2"
```

where

```
APIHOST=172.17.0.1
AUTH=path to auth.whisk.system
WSK_CLI= wsk path
NAMESPACE= whisk.system
```

Comment: The problem can be multifold: Is CouchDB up? Is it reachable by the Controller? You might want to join slack for easier debugging http://slack.openwhisk.org/

Comment: Yes counchDB is up. I dint know ho to chek if that is reachable via controller. I am also adding the header response •resp header info
 Resp Headers
 {
 "Connection": [
 "keep-alive"
 ],
 "Content-Length": [
 "117"
 ],
 "Content-Type": [
 "application/json; charset=UTF-8"
 ],
 "Date": [
 "Thu, 04 May 2017 08:14:09 GMT"
 ],
 "Server": [
"nginx/1.11.13"
 ]
 }

Comment: `grep db.host whisk.properties` if that value is not resolvable from inside the controller container, then the database is not accessible.

Comment: @user6062970 I have a ques as to how I check if that is resolvable from the controller container .. will it be by going into the controller container and then doing a ping from there?. Sorry if it is quite a naïve ques.

Comment: @user6062970 in my whisk.properties the db.host value is localhost

Answer (score 0):

This error comes when the DB host value is not resolvable from the controller container or when the DB which the controller trying to connect to is not created in the couch DB. Mine was the second case once __subjects db was there,
 it was able to run